# How to know whether an element has another element inside inside its class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
function A(){
    $('input[name="B[]"]').each(function() { 
        if(('$(this) .BtnSet .Child input:text[name="A[]"]').length){
         //yes the Child class is inside JRow class and has textboxes with name A[]
        }
    });
    return false;
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form onsubmit="return A()">
    <div class="row JRow">
     <input type="text" name="B[]"></input>
     <input type="text" name="B[]"></input>
        <div class="BtnSet">
            <div class="Child">
                <input type="text" name="A[]"></input>
                <input type="text" name="A[]"></input>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit"></input>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

I need to check whether B[] has a BtnSet class. Inside it, whether there is a Child class and inside it whether there are children elements like A[]. Have I done it precisely?
But the problem is in this case when I print alert('$(this) .BtnSet .Child input:text[name="A[]"]').length) the lenth is coming always as 45. Please explain me the reason for that ? Doesnt it gives the correct length as 2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the number 45 is the length of the **string** `$(this) .BtnSet .Child input:text[name="A[]"]` which you obviously don't require. What you need is the length of the two input elements which is within the `div.BtnSet`. So this should work

```
 $(this).siblings("div.BtnSet").first().find("input[name='A[]']").length;
```

Comment: Could you please briefly explain me this? What does it mean by method first()?

Comment: It finds the first `<div>` with the class `BtnSet` and then queries its decendents to find the `<input>` with name `A[]`. If you don't specify `first()`, then the query continues to find other siblings with the same class name

Comment: Oki... Thank u for replying.

Comment: @Lakmini I've updated my answer with the explanation on why the alert in your script would display the number 45

Comment: Is it necessary to put "div.BtnSet"? Its working even without div? What's the important of putting div.BtnSet? 
By the way Thank you so much for your explanation. I was struggling with this problem around for 2 days.

Comment: @Lakmini Happy I could help. For the current problem in your question you don't actually need the `div.BtnSet` but you may have other elements say `<a>` tags with the same class name `BtnSet`, so `div.BtnSet` would filter out only `<div>` elements with the class name `BtnSet`

Answer (score 2):

```
$(this).find("*[class='BtnSet']").length;
```

you are getting the string length, `$(this)` should be outside, and like @CoursesWeb pointed out these are not the children of the input elements with name=b[] but are siblings, you will have to use `siblings` for that!

```
 $(this).siblings("*[class='BtnSet']").length;
```

Comment: Thank you so much for replying..
Could you please explain me this, "$(this).siblings("*[class='BtnSet']").length; "

Comment: say A(any container element) got three elements inside it, B,C and D! then B,C & D are A's children, A is their parent(obviously!) and B,C & D are siblings to each other! so if you know B then you can find C & D using `siblings`. Take a look at the Jquery site for that!

Answer (score 0):

BtnSet is not insside B[], but is a child in `row jRow`, like B[].

Text Input tags has no child items.